# Trawling data from website

Tags: web-applications

What is the best method for getting prices of a website into an app? The prices are not being delivered to me, thus I need a method for automatically searching products and their prices of a website to use in an app on a daily basis. The software building the app has not been decided yet :)

Comment: This is an absurdly vague and overly-general question. Please focus your questions here to specific technical problems. First educate yourself about what you're trying to do, understand solutions available, and once you have some code you need someone to help you with, then come here. But always at least try to find the answer online if already available because redundantly asking easily answered or already answered beginner questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use curl in php to fetch specific data from a specific web page.
So my webapp calls a php script on my server to get data from that specific web page.

The following code utilises a feature on e-pages.dk that redirects to newest newspaper, the code then catches the number of the newest newspaper and returns that number to the calling webapp (code not shown).

```
$urltopost = 'http://www.e-pages.dk/vesthimmerlandsavis/';
$ch = curl_init($urltopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urltopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$log->write('URL: '.$urltopost, __FILE__, __LINE__);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Catch redirection
if (preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $response, $matches))
{
    $redirect = trim($matches[1]);
    // $redirect = '/vesthimmerlandsavis/472'
    $log->write('Redirection: '.$redirect, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
else
{
    die('Could not find newest newspaper');
}

// Catch number in /vesthimmerlandsavis/472
preg_match_all($pattern, $redirect, $matches);
$currentNumber = $matches[0][0];
$log->write('Current number: '.$currentNumber, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```